# How do I pass functions into Spark transformations during scalatest?

Tags: apache-spark, scalatest

I am using Flatspec to run a test and keep hitting an error because I pass a function into map. I've encountered this problem a few times, but just found a workaround by just using an anonymous function. That doesn't seem to be possible in this case. Is there a way of passing functions into transformations in scalatest?

code:

```
“test” should “fail” in { 
  val expected = sc.parallelize(Array(Array(“foo”, “bar”), Array(“bar”, “qux”)))

  def validateFoos(firstWord: String): Boolean = {
    if (firstWord == “foo”) true else false
  }

 val validated = expected.map(x => validateFoos(x(0)))
  val trues = expected.map(row => true)

  assert(None === RDDComparisons.compareWithOrder(validated, trues))
}
```

error: 
`org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable`

*This uses Holden Karau's Spark testing base:
https://github.com/holdenk/spark-testing-base

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "normal" way of handing this is to define the outer class to be serilizable, this is a bad practice in anything except for tests since you don't want to ship a lot of data around.

Comment: The more general way to this is to use static functions (put them in an companion object etc.)